# Why does this typedef code not create an instance

Tags: c, struct, structure, typedef

My understanding of the following structure code is that the last "s1" creates an instance of our new data type;

```
struct student
{
    int age;
    char *name;
}s1;
```

The addition of s1 is as if I had typed the following (after creating the structure type)

```
struct student s1;
```

However, if I use typedef, the code does not create an instance; instead it just makes s1 a synonym for struct student. Is this interpretation correct? I ask only because I find it odd that it doesn't work the same as the first block of code

```
typedef struct student
{
    int age;
    char *name;
}s1;
```

This doesn't create an instance of struct student called s1; it makes s1 the equivalent of typing struct student. What I find odd about this is that I thought typedef itself was enough to avoid typing struct student all the time. That is, if I had excluded s1 from the code block above, I could simply type

```
student s1;
```

instead of

```
struct student s1;
```

thanks to the addition of typedef.

If that is the case, then isn't this redundant:

```
typedef struct student
{
    int age;
    char *name;
} student;
```

I am already able to type simply student have C "substitute" in struct student simply by the first line of that last code block??

Comment: That's how C is specified to look and work, and there's really not much you can do about it. If you want to be able to use structure names directly as types, you should maybe start looking into C++?

Comment: And as for the last example, you could skip the structure name, so it's e.g. `typedef struct { ... } student;`

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct. `typedef` is a type qualifier, it creates a synonym for a type, not an instance of that type.

Comment: Thank you both - just wanted to make sure I was getting things right.

Comment: If it did the same thing with or without `typedef`, what would be the point of `typedef`?

Answer (score 2):

That's the way `typedef` works. By prepending it to what would otherwise be a variable definition, you create a declaration of a type alias. It's easier to see with a fundamental type:

```
int a; // a is a variable of type int
typedef int b; // b is a synonym for the type int
```

*"What I find odd about this is that I thought typedef itself was enough to avoid typing struct student all the time. That is, if I had excluded s1 from the code block above, I could simply type `student s1;`"*

No, that wouldn't work. [Try it](http://ideone.com/uSM8cq).

A `typedef` without a trailing name is syntactically correct, but meaningless.

```
int; // compiles, does nothing
typedef int; // compiles, does nothing
```